# Categorized View Category Column icon and Text

Tags: view, xpages

The icon and text are nested :( I couldn't give a little bit space to look better category Column in ve Xpages View..
[Find a a screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGUIW.png)

Comment: You will have better results pasting your screenshots in your question. Many of us in an office environments have many sites blocked, and because everything is recorded, we are careful what we click on.  Another thing I think will help you is take this tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With CSS codes this problem is solved. I found the style and object the added styles then fixed.